# Status Circle in UITableViewCell not appearing | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, tableview

Would someone please tell me why the status bubble is not appearing? I have declared and activated everything, to my knowledge. Nothing appears at all related to the status bubble. Note: inspectionCell was correctly registered in tableView setup.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if InspectionData.sharedInstance.partsData?.count != 0 {
            // get the part
            guard let part = InspectionData.sharedInstance.partsData?[indexPath.row] as? Part else {
                print("ERROR getting the part in cellForRowAt inside InspectionViewController")
                return UITableViewCell()
            }
            let inspectionCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: inspectionCell, for: indexPath) as! InspectionTableViewCell
            var inspectionContent = inspectionCell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            inspectionContent.text = part.title
            inspectionContent.secondaryText = part.location
            inspectionCell.isCompleted = part.completed
            inspectionCell.contentConfiguration = inspectionContent
            return inspectionCell
        } else {
            let placeholderCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: placeholderCell, for: indexPath)
            var placeholderContent = placeholderCell.defaultContentConfiguration()
            placeholderContent.text = "Reminder: Add parts to get started"
            placeholderCell.contentConfiguration = placeholderContent
            return placeholderCell
        }
    }

class InspectionTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    // create custom cell with status buble for the inspection parts tableView
    var statusBubble: UIView!
    var isCompleted: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            if isCompleted {
                statusBubble.backgroundColor = .green
            } else {
                statusBubble.backgroundColor = .red
            }
        }
    }
    
    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        statusBubble = UIView()
        statusBubble.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        statusBubble.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        contentView.addSubview(statusBubble)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            statusBubble.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            statusBubble.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
            statusBubble.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
            statusBubble.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

NOTE: I'm not trying to point out a specific item in the pictures... that UIView just happens to be selected in those pictures.

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

It turns out the statusBubble should not have been added to contentView, but the normal view instead.

```
contentView.addSubview(statusBubble)
```

changed to

```
addSubview(statusBubble)
```

I also changed the constraints to no longer reference the contentView.

Comment: Try adding a print statement to the didSet for your isCompleted property that logs the value being set. Make sure you are setting it in all cases. Also try using the UI inspector in Xcode to find the cell's view hierarchy and see if you can find the statusBubble view in your cell's view hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I put a print statement in the didSet and it is printing correctly.

Comment: I've added two screenshots to my post showing the hierarchy.

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out. Did Looking at the view hierarchy help you to figure out what was wrong?

Comment: It helped me realize it wasn't even being added to the view. I just googled other people's code and looked at how they added custom views to the cell and then compared it to mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `addSubview(statusBubble)`  because the `contentView` is a superview of cell.

on the other hand you could try to use a more elegant statement using

```
    lazy var statusBubble: UIView = {
     let view = UIView()
     view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
     view.layer.cornerRadius = 10
     return view
    }()
```

instead

```
var statusBubble: UIView!
```

Comment: Good catch, but it looks like the OP figured it out. (I missed that detail from his code. Sharp eye.)